# getEnclosingPrimaryTabId: Cannot get workspace from frameId: ext-comp-1017

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console, console, consoleintegrationtoolkit

Im trying to refresh the primaryTAB after Subtab close, and getting error "
**getEnclosingPrimaryTabId: Cannot get workspace from frameId: ext-comp-1017
ServiceDesk.js:304 refreshPrimaryTabById: Invalid ID: scc-st-1**"

any help will be much appreciated.

```
  <apex:page standardController="contact" extensions="EnrollmentConfirmationCtrl" standardStylesheets="false">

<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/34.0/integration.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/34.0/apex.js"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ClosePTab() {
        // get the ID of the current tab to close it
        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(closepSubtab);
    }  
    var closepSubtab = function closepSubtab(result) {
        //alert('closepSubtab Called XXXXZZZ'+result.id+'*****'+result);
        var tabId = result.id;
        sforce.console.closeTab(tabId);
        RefreshPrimaryTabById();
    };

    function RefreshPrimaryTabById() {
        //alert('Primary Tab refreshed successfully refreshSuccess');

        if(sforce.console.isInConsole()){
        sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds(function(resultTwo){
        sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(resultTwo.ids[0], true, function(){ /
        console.log('refreshed the primary tab');
        });
        });
        }
        else{
            console.log('we are not in console');
        }
    }
    function OpenRefreshSubtab() {
        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
    }

    var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result) {

        var primaryTabId = result.id;
        sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , '/apex/CanvasAppRefreshPage?scontrolCaching=1&id={!contact.ID}', true, 
        'Refreshing.....', null, openSuccess, 'Refreshing');
    };

    var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
        //Report whether we succeeded in opening the subtab
        if (result.success == true) {
            //alert('subtab successfully opened');
            setTimeout(function(){ 
            sforce.console.closeTab(result.id); }, 5000);
            } else {
            alert('subtab cannot be opened');
        }
    };
    sforce.console.addEventListener(sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.CLOSE_TAB,
    ClosePTab, { tabId : sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId() });


</script>

<apex:form id="myform"> 

    <apex:pageblock > 

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top"> 
        <apex:commandButton value="Close" onclick="OpenRefreshSubtab();return false" styleClass="buttonStyle" style="background:LightBlue;width:60px;float:Right;"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
        <apex:canvasApp developerName="CanvasApp_ProAdv" parameters="{'uNum':'{!contact.User_Num__c}','viewPage':'Enroll'}" width="100%" maxHeight="infinite"/>

    </apex:pageblock> 

</apex:form> 

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        function RefreshPrimaryTabById() {
                //alert('Primary Tab refreshed successfully refreshSuccess');
                var primaryTabId = 'scc-pt-0';
                //sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(primaryTabId);
                if(sforce.console.isInConsole()){
                    sforce.console.**getEnclosingPrimaryTabId**(refreshSuccess);
                }
                 else{
                   console.log('we are not in console');
                }
        }
```

change `getEnclosingTabId` to `getEnclosingPrimaryTabId`

You are passing subtabId.

**EDIT:**

Added the condition to check if user is in console or not

**EDIT:**
The below two lines are conflicting..You are closing the primary tab and then trying to refresh the same..

```
        sforce.console.closeTab(tabId);
        RefreshPrimaryTabById();
```

**EDIT:**

Updated code based on your comments:

```
function closeSubTab(tabId){ //pass the subtab Id
    sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function(result){
        deletedPrimaryTab = result.Id;
        sforce.console.closeTab(tabId); //deletes STAB1
        sforce.console.closeTab(deletedPrimaryTab); //close the PTAB2
        sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds(function(resultTwo){
            sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(resultTwo.ids[0], true, function(){ //Refresh the primary tab PTAB1
                console.log('refreshed the primary tab');
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Still same ..getEnclosingPrimaryTabId: Cannot get workspace from frameId: ext-comp-1041
ServiceDesk.js:304 refreshPrimaryTabById: Invalid ID: scc-pt-5

Comment: even i'm rying with "window.top.location='/console';"  it s reloading the page but reopening the closed tabs as well.

Comment: May be you are not in console

Comment: I edited the code to have the if condition to check if the user is already in console or not

Comment: im in console. i added the check as well. this is what im getting now...refreshPrimaryTabById: Invalid ID: scc-pt-1

Comment: Can you print all the primary Tab Ids opened by using this : `getPrimaryTabIds` and check if the Id is in that list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27467/discussion-between-javanoob-and-krforce).

Comment: let me put this way...i have a VF section on contact record with custome VF buttons which can open the VF page Primary tabs. on each VF page there is a VF button to do some updates which opens a subtab . when update done or after 5 secs, sub tab and parent should close and refresh the Contact Primary tab.

Comment: I am confused in understanding your business requirement but the problem I see from above the code snippet you gave is that you are trying to refresh the just closed primary tab. I can definitely help you but can you break down your requirement to the point where it is failing?

Comment: I have Primarytab called PTAB1 and Primarytab called PTAB2 and SubTab1 related to PrimaryTab2 called STAB1. When STAB1 closed automatically PTAB2 needs to close and refresh PTAB1.  Issue is with refreshing PTAB1.rest all working fine.

Comment: see the updated code..I hope this solves your situation.

Comment: No luck ..its not closing the PTAB2 and not refreshing PTAB1..getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined

Comment: im calling the the function from the addEventListener...sforce.console.addEventListener(sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.CLOSE_TAB,
    closeSubTab, { tabId : sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId() });

Comment: oops..there was syntax error..try now

Comment: it does refreshed the PTAB1 but didn't close the PATB2.

Comment: This is how im sending the tabid to the function do you think passing from Listener is the problem....sforce.console.addEventListener(sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.CLOSE_TAB,
    closeSubTab, { tabId : sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId() });

Comment: i see the value for deletedPrimaryTab is getting value as undefined thats why its not able to close it.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue, your comment did helped me to resolve it and i have also edited and updated the code in the post. Please post your edited code as the Answer to mark it as resolved.  Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @KrForce sorry the reason I did not update my post with answer was because you solved it finally and I just gave some Idea.